# Order of multiple middleware in React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, middleware

What happen if I have multiple middleware (lets say 3 for the exemple), all catching a single action ? Do they trigger in the order defined in the store creation ?

```
createStore(reducer,applyMiddleware(middle1, middle2, middle3));
```

middle1 will get triggered first, then middle2, then middle3 ? (when calling next() )
Can I on a specific action force middle3 to be called before middle2 ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The middleware pipeline exactly matches the order that you passed to `applyMiddleware()`.  So, in that example:

- calling `store.dispatch()` passes the action to `middle`
- when `middle1` calls `next(action)`, it goes to `middle2`
- when `middle2` calls `next(action)`, it goes to `middle3`
- when `middle3` calls `next(action)`, it goes to the actual store and the reducer logic is executed

And no, you cannot reorder middleware after the store has been created.

Comment: Do you if there's a good way to write a test to check if middlewares are being applied in the correct order? Do you think it's beneficial to even do that in the first place?

Comment: I can't immediately think of one, and no, I don't think that's worth testing.  That's simply going to be a matter of a couple lines of code in your app setup logic.